# Linq Query Problems with Anonymous Types

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

Cant Figure Out Whats The Problem

```
If IsNothing(_cartItem) Then

    Dim SPDB As New SamplePicturesDataContext()
    Dim q = From sp In SPDB.Pictures _
            Where sp.Id = ItemId _
            Select New With {.Pic_Desc = sp.Description, _
                             .Pic_Title = sp.PictureName}
    _cartItem = New CartItem(q.Pic_Desc, 1, q.Pic_Title)
Else


Error   1   'Pic_Desc' is not a member of 'System.Linq.IQueryable(Of <anonymous type>)'.    

Error   2   'Pic_Title' is not a member of 'System.Linq.IQueryable(Of <anonymous type>)'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the type is `IQueryable` you need to enumerate over the query so that it is evaluated and then it can be used.

This should work (note I do not check for `Nothing` which you should do):

```
Dim SPDB As New SamplePicturesDataContext()
    Dim q = (From sp In SPDB.Pictures _
            Where sp.Id = ItemId _
            Select New With {.Pic_Desc = sp.Description, _
                             .Pic_Title = sp.PictureName}).SingleOrDefault() ' assume singleordefault due to matching on id values.

    _cartItem = New CartItem(q.Pic_Desc, 1, q.Pic_Title)
```

Comment: was this helpful or not?